# I have no excuse VS I have no excuses

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which one sounds more natural in this situation ?

Putin: Obama you're late again !   tell me why

Obama: **I have no excuse ( excuses ? )**

Comment: "Which sounds more natural" is entirely a matter of individual opinion. Stack Exchange is not a place for such a beauty-contest: it's a place for objective answers. You could ask "Which is used more often?" but please note that you should have done some research yourself into the answer [and show that you have].

Answer (score 1):

> I have no excuse

is fine. If you don't have one of something, you certainly don't have more than one.